# Solving Markov chain Conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

[image]

i am struggling to do the first part which im certain is needed to also complete the other parts aswell, i know i can use the property of conditional probability however i am unsure of how to find for example p(X4=j,X3=2)

Answer (score 1):

Hint :
$$
P(X_3 = 2) = \sum_{i=1}^2 P(X_3 = 2 |  X_1 = i)P(X_1 = i)
$$

Now, for each $i$, $P(X_1 = i) = 0.5$. Furthermore, we have :
$$
P(X_3 = 2 | X_1 = i) = \sum_{j = 1}^2 P(X_3 = 2 | X_2 = j , X_1 = i) P(X_2 = j | X_1 = i) \\ = \sum_{j=1}^2 P(X_3 = 2 | X_2 = j) P(X_2 = j | X_1 = i) = \sum_{j=1}^2 p_{i,j}p_{j,2}
$$

Whence combining :
$$
P(X_3 = 2) = \sum_{i,j=1}^2 p_{i,j}p_{j,2}P(X_1 = i)
$$

Which can be calculated. Writing it out explicitly :
$$
P(X_3 = 2) = \\
p_{1,1}p_{1,2}P(X_1 = 1) \\ + p_{2,1}p_{1,2}P(X_1 = 2) \\ + p_{1,2}p_{2,2}P(X_1 = 2 ) \\ + p_{2,2}p_{2,2} P(X_1 = 2)
$$

Now you know all the quantities above, thence can conclude.

Now for parts $b$ and $c$, use the Bayes' rule :
$$
p(X_2 = 1 | X_3 = 2) = \frac{P(X_3 = 2 | X_2 = 1)P(X_2 = 1)}{P(X_3 = 2)}
$$

which can be calculated. Similarly the third one.

Third one  :
$$
P(X_1 = 1 | X_3 = 2) = \frac{P(X_3 = 2 |X_1 = 1)P(X_1 = 1)}{P(X_3 = 2)}
$$

The $P(X_3 = 2 | X_1 = 1)$ can be calculated as $p_{1,1}p_{1,2} + p_{1,2}p_{2,2}$ from the formula mentioned in part $1$. The rest are known.

Comment: on the line after you said whence combining im still not sure how to solve the RHS part

Comment: also for the bottom part of what you wrote for part b) and c) wouldn't it be easier to leave it as p(X3 = 2 )

Comment: Yes, it would, now that I think of it! I'll expand the "whence combining" line anyway.

Comment: im assuming p(X2 = 1 ) would follow the exact route as for p(X3 = 2)

Comment: That's right, namely $P(X_2 = 1) = \sum_{i=1}^2 P(X_2 = 1 | X_1 = i) P(X_1 = i)$ You should get $P(X_2 = 1) = 0.45$.

Comment: so p(X2=1 ) =  (0.2 * 0.5) + ( 0.7 * 0.5) = 0.45 following the formula and matrix given on the question ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: i got 0.525 for p (x3=2 ) ,  would this be right ?  and for p(X2=1| X3=2 ) = 0.6

Comment: The first is correct, the second we have $P(X_3 = 2 | X_2 = 1) = 0.8$, and $P(X_2 = 1) = 0.45$ and $P(X_3 = 2) = 0.525$, so the answer is $\frac{0.8 \times 0.45}{0.525}$ which won't be $0.6$, will it? It will be $\frac{24}{35}$.

Comment: oh yeah that would be correct , i accidentally swapped the i and j around

Comment: No problem. I hope you have got the gist of this answer.

Comment: for part c ) im stuck again since i used bayes therom however it dosnt fall within the use of the formula provided  even though i know p(X1 =1 ) = 0.5

Comment: See the edit now.

Comment: i had a feeling that was the way to do it and i got (0.8*0,2) + (0.3*0.8)=2/5

Comment: Yes, that is correct.